# How to convert from List<B> = IQueryable<A>

Tags: c#, wcf

I got two classes A & B. Also, I need to convert an object of `IQueryable<A>` to an object of `List<B>`. So what is the best practice in doing so? What I have in mind is to first transfer obj `IQueryable<A>` to `List<A>` by "obj.ToList();" But I am not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 7):

```
List<B> myList = myQueryableOfA.Select(a => ConvertAToB(a)).ToList();
```

Where `myQueryableOfA` is `IQueryable<A>` and `ConvertAToB` returns `B`.

If `ConvertAToB` just a method, you can just do this.

```
.Select(ConvertAToB)
```

Comment: @Vash - that is just on  `List<T>`

Comment: true I generally wanted to refer to `Converter<TInput, TOutput>` and ConvertAll<TInput, TOutput> and the List<T> is an example of usage.